# Importing csv with Freespire.xls adding blank row

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I currently have a process for work that uploads a `.CSV` into a `DataTable` object.

From there, I have a custom `DataTable` datatype in SQL, and a stored procedure to insert everything from the passed in datatype, to a real table in SQL.

Everything is working properly, and the data gets uploaded, the only problem is that every other row, is a row of entirely NULL values. The spreadsheet does not have blank rows in between, but there are instances where a column may not have values.

Does anyone have any advice or help on how to fix this or a better way to import my csv into a DataTable? the file is generated as .CSV every time from an oracle query that somebody runs and saves.

**Code:**

```
public static DataTable GetDataFromFile(string filePath)
{
    Workbook book = new Workbook();
    book.LoadFromFile(@"" + filePath, ",");
    DataTable table = book.Worksheets[0].ExportDataTable();
    return table;

}
```

Edited the question, the above code is adding blank lines to the .CSV OR there are hidden line breaks in Excel that I cannot see, how can I fix these blank rows being added.

Comment: double check the spreadsheet for extra end of line char()
this can cause an extra blank row of data.

Comment: How can I do this? The last column is a date, but I see no line breaks in the values.  I am going to quickly see what it looks like when i put it into a dgv

Comment: I use a word editor like Notepad++ or programmers_notepad that can display end of line char(). Viewing the data in a DataGridView is a good idea too.

Comment: Yes, it still occurs, and so it must be the spreadsheet. I tried what you said, and each row ends with `09-JUL-18 05.15.10.000000000 PM` no quotes and no ending comma. Is there a weird reason i don't know about in excel or in csv's for this happening

Comment: Just found out that I can export out of oracle as a Xlsx file May have to do that although that would be unfortunate

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle to SQL using ODBC**

You could connect the oracle database to the sql database using odbc, then do a direct data transfer into the temp table.

Drivers: [Oracle ODBC Drivers](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-098155.html)

Usage:[Connect to an Oracle Data Source (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-oracle-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)

This topic shows you how to connect to an Oracle data source from the Choose a Data Source or Choose a Destination page of the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. There are several data providers that you can use to connect to Oracle.

> Important

The detailed requirements and prerequisites for connecting to an Oracle database are beyond the scope of this Microsoft article. This article assumes that you already have Oracle client software installed and that you can already connect successfully to the target Oracle database. For more info, consult your Oracle database administrator or the Oracle documentation.

Connect to Oracle with the .Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle
After you select .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle on the Choose a Data Source or Choose a Destination page of the wizard, the page presents a grouped list of options for the provider. Many of these are unfriendly names and unfamiliar settings. Fortunately, you only have to provide two or three pieces of information. You can ignore the default values for the other settings.

> Note

The connection options for this data provider are the same whether Oracle is your source or your destination. That is, the options you see are the same on both the Choose a Data Source and the Choose a Destination pages of the wizard.

Required info   .Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle property
Server name Data Source
Authentication (login) info User ID and Password; or, Integrated Security
You don't have to enter the connection string in the ConnectionString field of the list. After you enter individual values for the Oracle server name (Data Source) and login info, the wizard assembles the connection string from the individual properties and their values.

> Connect to Oracle with .NET provider

Connect to Oracle with the Microsoft ODBC driver for Oracle
ODBC drivers aren't listed in the drop-down list of data sources. To connect with an ODBC driver, start by selecting the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC as the data source on the Choose a Data Source or Choose a Destination page. This provider acts as a wrapper around the ODBC driver.

Here's the generic screen that you see immediately after selecting the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC.

> Connect to Oracle with ODBC before

Options to specify (ODBC Driver for Oracle)
Note

The connection options for this data provider and ODBC driver are the same whether Oracle is your source or your destination. That is, the options you see are the same on both the Choose a Data Source and the Choose a Destination pages of the wizard.

To connect to Oracle with the ODBC Driver for Oracle, assemble a connection string that includes the following settings and their values. The format of a complete connection string immediately follows the list of settings.

Tip

Get help assembling a connection string that's just right. Or, instead of providing a connection string, provide an existing DSN (data source name) or create a new one. For more info about these options, see Connect to an ODBC Data Source.

> Driver

The name of the ODBC driver, Microsoft ODBC for Oracle.

> Server

The name of the Oracle server.

> Uid and Pwd

The user id and password to connect.

> Connection string format

Here's the format of a typical connection string.

Copy

`Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=myServerAddress;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

> Enter the connection string

Enter the connection string in the ConnectionString field, or enter the DSN name in the Dsn field, on the Choose a Data Source or Choose a Destination page. After you enter the connection string, the wizard parses the string and displays the individual properties and their values in the list.

Here's the screen that you see after entering the connection string.

> Connect to Oracle with ODBC

What's my Oracle server name?
Run one of the following queries to get the name of your Oracle server.

SELECT host_name FROM v$instance

or

SELECT sys_context('USERENV','SERVER_HOST') FROM dual

> Other data providers and more info

For info about how to connect to Oracle with a data provider that's not listed here, see Oracle connection strings. This third-party site also contains more info about the data providers and the connection parameters described on this page.

Comment: Honestly when I first started the project, i planned on connecting to the server itself, but realized quickly oracle is another realm of SQL but you just gave me a S+ answer. Ill keep ya posted on how i used it.